# Inharmonious union symbol

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

Does anyone know how to write this mathematical expression more "pretty"? The white spaces on the right and left of the union symbol (U) bother me. Below is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{aligned}
             \left(\bigcup \limits_{q \in\{q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4,q_6,q_7,q_8,q_9,q_{10},q_{11},q_{12},q_{13},q_{14}\}} \Delta(q,0)\right)
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Output:[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could specify your desired appearance?  One thing you could do would be manually to insert a lot of negative space before $\Delta(q, 0)$, but that space occupied by the subscript has to go somewhere, so it would then stick out to the right.  Another (better!) option would be to write $\bigcup_{i = 1}^{14} \Delta(q_i, 0)$.  It's hard to say what's best without knowing more about your application.

Comment: @LSpice I liked this suggestion: $\bigcup_{i = 1}^{14} \Delta(q_i, 0)$. Thank you.
But in case the numbers are not consecutive ( example: $\bigcup \limits_{q \in \{q_1,q_2,q_3,q_7,q_8,q_{11}\}} \Delta(q,0)$ ) how could I do it?

Comment: [Re](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1653712), it depends on whether you are stuck on an approach and looking for a way to bend TeX to your will—in which case you need to describe exactly what you want—or are willing slightly to re-work the text. If the latter, one approach would be to say something like "Let $S = \{q_1, q_2, q_3, q_7, q_8, q_{11}\}$, and consider $\bigcup_{q \in S} \Delta(q, 0)$" (or you could give a name to the set of indices instead of the actual set of interest, or any number of other things).  But then this is not a TeX question.

Comment: With the given indices, I would adapt David Carlisle's substack to `1\le i\le 14\\i\neq5`.  How unconsecutive to things get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does one of the following solutions strike your fancy? The first without tall parentheses, the second with `\bigg`-sized ones. (The ones produced by `\left(` and `\right)` are simply too tall, typographically speaking.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\bigcup_{q \in Q} \Delta(q,0) \quad\text{or}\quad
\biggl(\, \bigcup \limits_{q \in Q} \Delta(q,0) \biggr)
\]
where $Q = \{ q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4, q_6, q_7, q_8, q_9, q_{10}, q_{11}, q_{12}, q_{13}, q_{14}\}$.
\end{document}
```

Do note that I've gotten rid of code junk such as the unneeded `aligned` environment and the `\limits` qualifier.

Answer (score 2):

It would look better without the outer brackets, if they are not needed but I left them in here.

i would use (2) if this is real data but if in your real case you do need a list, then (3)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
             \left(\bigcup_{q \in\{q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4,q_6,q_7,q_8,q_9,q_{10},q_{11},q_{12},q_{13},q_{14}\}} \Delta(q,0)\right)
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
             \Bigl(\bigcup_{i=1}^{14} \Delta(q_i,0)\Bigr)
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
             \Biggl(\bigcup_{q \in\left\{\substack{q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4,\\
                                    q_6,q_7,q_8,\\q_9,q_{10},q_{11},q_{12},\\
                                   q_{13},q_{14}}\right\}} \Delta(q,0)\Biggr)
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```